# PHP content management system which tracks content through git

Tags: php, git, content-management-system, markdown

Are there any content management systems which use git for tracking content and support markdowns? I have heard of [git-blog](https://github.com/elliottcable/git-blog) and [WiGit](http://el-tramo.be/git/wigit) , any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: These may be of help, might require some massaging. http://developmentseed.org/blog/2011/09/09/jekyll-github-pages/

Comment: This may be a bit off the scope but in case someone finds this useful: [Stacey](http://staceyapp.com/) uses plain markdown-files. There are also [a few](http://www.fearofconfusion.com/2012/01/three-markdown-dropbox-bloggging.html) Dropbox-powered blogging engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Phrozn: http://www.phrozn.info/en/ - it's pretty much a port of Jekyll to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I made [Orbiter](http://viaorbiter.com/) ([on GitHub](https://github.com/kasparsd/orbiter)) for creating simple websites out of markdown documents via PHP. It uses Mustache for templating and supports Markdown by default. It uses plain text files as source documents so you can use both Git and Dropbox for syncing the documents. It is also dynamic, which means you don't have to manually "generate" your website after every update.